# Как реализовать добавление свойств к сущности?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Имеется проект .Net Core 2.0, ASP.Net Core 2.0, EF-Core 2.0 с простой сущностью `Product`. Стоит задача реализовать возможность добавления определенных пользователем свойств к продукту. Проблема заключается в необходимости иметь различные по типу поля (`DateTime`, `int`, `string`, etc.). На данный момент имеются следующие идеи.

Добавить в модель сущность `ProductProperty` с отношением many-to-many к сущности `Product`, но это будет работать только если все свойства одного типа.

Сериализовывать все свойства (XML, JSON) и сохранять в одном свойстве сущности Product, но в этом случае скорее всего возникнут проблемы с поиском.

Сохранять определенный пользователем тип в дополнительном свойстве сущности ProductProperty, само свойство сохранять как string, но опять же поиск и в принципе такое решение выглядит как-то не очень.

Определить для каждого типа свойство в `Product` (`DateTimeProperties`, `StringProperties`, `BoolProperties`, etc.) и определять для каждого из созданных свойств отношение many-to-many.

Скорее всего я не первый сталкиваюсь с такой необходимостью и существуют какие-либо приемлимые способы решения проблемы. Каким образом можно добавить определенные пользователем свойства к сущности?

Comment: Простое решение в лоб: one-to-many таблица с атрибутами продуктов `ProductProperties (id, productId, name, intVal, stringVal, dateTimeVal, ....)`

Comment: Я сталкивался и делал кучу таблиц типа ```BoolProperty```, ```BoolPropertyValue```, связывал такие таблицы с продуктами. Минусы - много связей, много таблиц, на каждый чих, связвнный с полями продукта, было необходимо работать со всеми таблицами. Также сложность добавления нового типа данных. Плюсы - строгая типизация на уровне БД, поиск облегчается индексированными представлениями, поиск по конкретным полям происходит с учетом типа данных (например, найти продукт с датой создания 8 марта - ищешь по таблице, что хранит даты, не надо ничего парсить)

Comment: @free_ze один-ко-многим сюда не подойдет, т.к. одно и то-же свойство должно использоваться в разных продуктах. Так-же нужно сохранять используемый тип, иначе будет невозможно определить способ отображения в GUI при NULL значениях. С поиском не будет проблем?

Comment: @tym32167 а как это будет выглядеть в DB модели? Не могли бы Вы привести пример?

Comment: @XelaNimed, внезапно) Зачем вам это? Вы хотите, чтобы изменение свойства аффектило сразу на все продукты? Используемый тип вы и поймете по тому, что оно единственное будет не NULL.

Comment: @free_ze к примеру изменение имени свойства у продуктов одной и той-же категории (width, length, etc.), да и тому-же избыточно, на мой взгляд, сохранять каждый раз имя свойства, которое может быть "вбито" в разных вариантах написания (length, Len., L). 
Получается что для определения типа нужно будет для всех определяемых свойств разрешать NULL-значения - это нормальная практика?

Comment: @XelaNimed, у продуктов будет некий фиксированный набор свойств? Ничто не мешает отыскать записи по имени, а потом его же и поменять. Все зависит от функциональности, которая нужна. Вот, выясняется, что есть категории и групповое переименование свойств продуктов в ней.

Comment: @XelaNimed это было около 10 лет назад, я могу быть неточным, но вроде схема выглядела так: Product{id, name}(1)-(M)BoolPropertyValue{id, productId, propertyId, value}(M)-(1)Propery{id, name}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакой типизации на уровне БД. Иначе можно утонуть в лишних таблицах. На `Value` поставил бы `nvarchar(max)`. Приведение типов на DAL слое.

В конкретно вашей задаче я спроектировал бы БД так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но. По хорошему не может быть абсолютно разных типов продуктов. Я бы разбил на категории и воспользовался бы [Table Per Hierarchy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) подходом.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ! В приведенном Вами примере можно лишь сохранить текстовое значение. Как в этом случае использовать фильтрацию при выборке? Ведь "5" > "4" не будет работать.

Comment: Это может подойти для небольших выборок. При количестве продуктов в 1М, и пропертей в 10М, фильтрация, учитывающая тип данных, будет оочень долго работать

Comment: @XelaNimed _Приведение типов на DAL слое_ - написал же вам. Соответственно, выбрать _5 > 4_ на уровне БД вы не сможете. Если вам это надо - пользуйте решение, следующее за _Но_.

Comment: @AGS17 ```5 > 4 на уровне БД вы не сможете``` Сможет, только если запрос руками писать.

Comment: @tym32167 подразумевалось _выбрать 5 > 4 на уровне БД с помощью EF_

Comment: @AGS17 Сконструировать запрос средствами Linq to EF вряд ли получится, но если использовать Database-first, то хранимка/представление + EF должно сработать. Другой вопрос - надо ли оно.

Comment: @tym32167 в EF Core нет DB-First.

Comment: @AGS17 большое спасибо за подсказку TPH, не знал о таком.

Comment: @XelaNimed не знал об этом, спасибо )

Comment: @tym32167 делал у себя подробное, с небольшими отличиями: у меня  есть таблица справочник типы параметров(строка, число, и.т.д). а в таблице в которой будут хранится значения параметров, для каждого типа отдельная колонка